# TFS Shelveset/Gated Check-in fail: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred

Tags: tfs, msbuild, gated-checkin

When attempting to run a TFS 2015 build with a changeset specified (or gated checkin) we get an error at the start of the build:

[image: error]

So this looks to be a problem with the `TF UNSHELVE` command...
I logged onto the server as the TFS agent user account and ran the command manually:

[image]

This worked **AFTER** I configured the tf workspaces collection as it requested. See the initial command error-ed.

Any ideas where I can find better information about what's actually failing? I'm not getting a good error message. There's nothing relevant that I can see in the eventvwr.msc log.

- The build runs fine if a changeset isn't specified
- I deleted the workspace and allowed the build to re-create the it - didn't help

---

EDIT: Further info, looks like a bug in TFS? Unless anyone knows a workaround then looks like we'll have to postpone GC until we update TFS.

[image]

Comment: Try running the build with the variable `system.debug` = `true` configured. That should provide more details. Alternatively, check the `_diag` folder of the agent for a more specific error message.

Comment: TFS 2015 has a pretty old version of the build agent and accompanying tasks. The Agent and tasks have been massively improved since this `v1` release. Azure DevOps Server 2019 basically ships with version `v3` of most tasks and has seen more than 60 sprints in which improvements were delivered. Upgrading to TFS 2017 or Azure DevOps Server 2019 is highly recommended.

Comment: @jessehouwing Made some progress - found out more info about the error message in the edit above. Seems like a TFS bug

Comment: Looks like a bug indeed.Are you running the latest TFS 2015 update and the latest version of the agtn available for that update?